# Several pin colors on same map in MKMapView

Tags: iphone, annotations, ios4, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView` in my app with several pins on it and I'd like to set different colors for each pin. My view controller is implementing `MKMapViewDelegate` and I've defined viewForAnnotation method.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
        initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
    return annView;
}
```

It works fine and changes pin color to green. However the color is changed for all pins and I'd like to color them with several colors (based on some criteria I'd define, lets assume I want to have odd pins green and even pins yellow or something as simple as that). How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this issue by using images instead of pinColor. This way I can have as many pins as I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(annotation.fillsYourCriteria)  
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;  
else  
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorYellow;  
return annView;
```

Something as simple as that?

Comment: Not really. API provides only three pin colors, what I want to get is have more of them.

Comment: You could use https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSPinAnnotation if you want to create custom Pins with whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the same issue then I solved by using this code

```
if([[pinView.annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Current Location"])
{
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; 
}
else
{
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple; 
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the APIs provide only 3 colors to choose from. In my case I needed more than that.

Comment: Ya as you said that is exceptional case.We can not add more than the three colors instead of images.